# Python 2.7: Downloads PDFS with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click certain links on a webpage to download PDF files automatically using selenium. My problem is that i want to click on 3 different links that are named the same: "Lap Times". i have tried using their xpaths in `find_element_by_xpath` but the download does not take place.

If i use `find_element_by_text("Lap Times")`, only the last link named "Lap Times" is clicked.

Here is the webpage: https://www.fia.com/events/fia-formula-one-world-championship/season-2016/event-timing-information-5

Here is my code:

```
years = ["2016", "2017"]
races = []

for year in years:
    for i in range(20):
        page = "https://www.fia.com/events/fia-formula-one-world-championship/season-" + year + "/event-timing-information-" + str(i)
        races.append(page)


def download_pdfs(races, xpath):

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/vnd.pdf")
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/vnd.pdf")
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "");
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
    profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True);
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

    for race in races:
        browser.get(race)
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
        except:
            "cannot download pdf:" + str(race)
```

**Download FP3 Lap Times PDFs by clicking on link "Lap Times" below the header "Third Practice"**

```
download_pdfs(races, "//*[@id='page-wrapper']/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/ul[5]/li[1]/p/span/a")
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing in an XPath, Try using this specifically:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Lap Times')]")[1].click()
```

Note the plural version of the find by method here; we're asking for all of the links with the text "Lap Times", then choosing the second one in the list (which is the Third Practice) to click on.

I also recommend that you do not use the open "except".  either specify an exception, like TimeoutException, or don't use the try/except block at all.  You're missing out on details of what problem is being reported.